# Spring autowire object using factory method

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to figure out how to change this java code into spring

```
private MyObject myObject = MyObjectFactory.getService();
```

In my Foo.java class I have

```
@Autowired
private MyObject myObject;
```

In the spring xml, I have:

```
<bean id="MyObject" class="path.to.MyObjectFactory" factory-method="getService"></bean>

<bean id="Foo" class="path.to.Foo">
    <property name="myObject" ref="MyObject"/>
</bean>
```

The error is

```
No matching bean of type [path.to.MyObject] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you try to inject a object of type `MyObjectFactory` into path.to.Foo, where a object of type `MyObject` is expected. please change your code like this:

Foo:

```
public class Foo {
    private MyObject myObject;
    public void setMyObject(MyObject value) { myObject=value;}
}
```

MyObjectFactory:

```
public class MyObjectFactory {
    public MyObject getService() {
        return new MyObject();
    }
}
```

spring xml:

```
<bean class="MyObjectFactory" id="factory" />
<bean id="myObject" factory-bean="factory" factory-method="getService" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="Foo" class="path.to.Foo">
    <property name="myObject" ref="MyObject"/>
</bean>
```

By the way, `@Autowired` and `<property ...>` express the same thing in your case, so you could leave the one or the other out.

**UPDATE:**

take a look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) for more information factory beans in spring.

i assumed you do not want a singleton, that is why i added `scope="prototype"`. remove it, if your instance of `MyObject` suppose to be a singleton.